# Problems when trying to expand pcpartpicker API

Tags: python, json

Pcpartpicker API: https://github.com/nynhex/PCPartPicker-API

I learn python at the moment and saw that none of the unofficial pcpartpicker APIs are really great. They all lack a lot of features. So I copied the source code and am now  just trying to test it.

I copied '_productsData.py' script as is.

```py
productLookup = {
    "cpu": {
        2: "speed",
        3: "cores",
        4: "tdp"
    },
    "cpu-cooler": {
        2: "fan-rpm",
        3: "noise level"
    },
    "motherboard": {
        2: "socket",
        3: "form-factor",
        4: "ram-slots",
        5: "max-ram"
    },
    "memory": {
        2: "speed",
        3: "type",
        4: "cas",
        5: "modules",
        6: "size",
        7: "price/gb"
    },
    "internal-hard-drive": {
        2: "series",
        3: "form",
        4: "type",
        5: "capacity",
        6: "cache",
        7: "price/gb"
    },
    "video-card": {
        2: "series",
        3: "chipset",
        4: "memory",
        5: "core-clock"
    },
    "power-supply": {
        2: "series",
        3: "form",
        4: "efficiency",
        5: "watts",
        6: "modular"
    },
    "case": {
        2: "type",
        3: "ext525b",  # EXTERNAL 5.25" BAYS
        4: "int35b",   # INTERNAL 3.5" BAYS
        5: "power-supply"
    },
    "case-fan": {
        2: "color",
        3: "size",
        4: "rpm",
        5: "airflow",
        6: "noise-level"
    },
    "fan-controller": {
        2: "form-factor",
        3: "channels",
        4: "channel-wattage"
    },
    "thermal-paste": {
        2: "amount"
    },
    "optical-drive": {
        2: "bd",
        3: "dvd",
        4: "cd",
        5: "bd-write",
        6: "dvd-write",
        7: "cd-write"
    },
    "sound-card": {
        2: "chipset",
        3: "channels",
        4: "bits",
        5: "snr",
        6: "sample-rate"
    },
    "wired-network-card": {
        2: "interface",
        3: "ports"
    },
    "wireless-network-card": {
        2: "interface",
        3: "protocols"
    },
    "monitor": {
        2: "resolution",
        3: "size",
        4: "response-time",
        5: "ips"
    },
    "external-hard-drive": {
        2: "series",
        3: "type",
        4: "capacity",
        5: "price/gb"
    },
    "headphones": {
        2: "type",
        3: "microphone",
        4: "wireless",
        5: "frequency-response"
    },
    "keyboard": {
        2: "style",
        3: "color",
        4: "switch-type",
        5: "backlit"
    },
    "mouse": {
        2: "tracking",
        3: "connection",
        4: "color"
    },
    "speakers": {
        2: "configuration",
        3: "total-wattage",
        4: "frequency-response"
    },
    "ups": {
        2: "capacity-w",
        3: "capacity-va"
    }
}
```

In 'engine.py' I pasted the contents of 'pcpartpicker.py'.

```
from json import loads as jsonloads
from ._productsData import productLookup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

baseURL = "https://pcpartpicker.com"

def setRegion(region):
    """
    Change the region for the pcpartpicker.com requests. Supports (case insesetive):
    "au", "be", "ca", "de", "es", "fr", "in", "ie", "it", "nz", "uk", "us"
    """
    global baseURL
    region = region.lower()
    
    if region in ["au", "be", "ca", "de", "es", "fr", "in", "ie", "it", "nz", "uk", "us"]:
        baseURL = "https://" + ((region + ".") if region != "us" else "") + "pcpartpicker.com"
    else:
        raise ValueError("region \"{}\" not supported".format(region))

class productLists(object):
    """
    For scraping product lists such as
    https://pcpartpicker.com/products/cpu-cooler/
    """

    @staticmethod
    def _getPage(partType, pageNum, returnMaxPageNum=False):
        """
        A private method to GET, decode, and parse a page from pcpartpicker
        If returnMaxPageNum is True, this function will only return an Int
        """
        if partType not in productLookup:
            raise ValueError("partType invalid")
        r = get(baseURL + "/products/" + partType + "/fetch?page=" + str(pageNum))
        parsed = jsonloads(r.content.decode("utf-8"))
        if returnMaxPageNum:
            return parsed["result"]["paging_data"]["page_blocks"][-1]["page"]
        return BeautifulSoup(parsed["result"]["html"], "html.parser")
    
    @staticmethod
    def totalPages(partType):
        """
        Returns the total number of pages for partType
        """
        return productLists._getPage(partType, 1, True)

    @staticmethod
    def getProductList(partType, pageNum=0):
        """
        Returns results for pageNum. If pageNum is left to default, get all
        pages. pageNum starts at 1
        """
        if pageNum == 0:
            start_pageNum, end_pageNum = 1, productLists.totalPages(partType)
        else:
            start_pageNum, end_pageNum = pageNum, pageNum

        cpuList = []
        for pageNum in range(start_pageNum, end_pageNum+1):
            soup = productLists._getPage(partType, pageNum)
            for row in soup.find_all("tr"):
                cpuDetails = {}
                for count, value in enumerate(row):
                    text = value.get_text().strip()

                    if count in productLookup[partType]:
                        cpuDetails[productLookup[partType][count]] = text
                    elif count == 1:
                        cpuDetails["name"] = text
                    elif count == len(row)-2:
                        cpuDetails["price"] = text
                    elif count == len(row)-3:
                        cpuDetails["ratings"] = text.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
                    else:
                        try:
                            if value.a["class"] == ["btn-mds", "pp_add_part"]:
                                cpuDetails["id"] = value.a["href"].replace("#", "")
                        except TypeError:
                            pass  # Not <a> tag
                        except KeyError:
                            pass  # No class

                cpuList.append(cpuDetails)
        return cpuList
```

At last I copied the code snippet from the documentation into the file 'test.py'.

```py
import engine as pcpp

print("Total CPU pages:", pcpp.productLists.totalPages('cpu'))

cpu_info = pcpp.productLists.getProductList("cpu", 1)

for cpu in cpu_info:
    print(cpu["name"], ":", cpu["price"])

pcpp.setRegion("uk")
print("\nRegion changed to UK")

cpu_info_uk = pcpp.productLists.getProductList("cpu")

for cpu in cpu_info_uk:
    print(cpu["name"], ":", cpu["price"])
```

When I now try to run 'test.py' then I get this JSON decoder error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Malte\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print("Total CPU pages:", pcpp.productLists.totalPages('cpu'))
  File "C:\Users\Malte\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\engine.py", line 40, in totalPages
    return productLists._getPage(partType, 1, True)
  File "C:\Users\Malte\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\engine.py", line 31, in _getPage
    parsed = jsonloads(data)
  File "C:\Users\Malte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Malte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Malte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could someone explain it for me what is happening, please? Why is this JSON method used? Isn't it a html I receive from the get request?